# Embedding seaborn clustermap into tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, seaborn

I'm attempting to display a seaborn clustermap in a tkinter window.

I can embed seaborn heatmaps; however, clustermaps fail to appear in the tkinter window and an empty seaborn frame appears instead.

```
#Libraries
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

#Returns plot for tkinter to display
def create_plot(): 

    #creates dataset
    data = np.random.rand(50,11)

    #Defines plot
    plot, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

    #Does work - Outputs heatmap
    #sns.heatmap(data, cmap='YlGnBu')

    #Doesn't work - Should output clustermap
    sns.clustermap(data,cmap='YlGnBu',metric = 'correlation',z_score=0) 

    return plot

#Generating tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
figure = create_plot()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

The clustermap can be correctly displayed inline with the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline
data = np.random.rand(50,11)
sns.clustermap(data,cmap='YlGnBu',metric = 'correlation',z_score=0)
```

Is there something different about clustermaps, how can they be embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clustermap creates its own figure. So you need to return this figure to use it elsewhere.

```
#Libraries
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

#Returns plot for tkinter to display
def create_plot(): 

    data = np.random.rand(50,11)

    g = sns.clustermap(data,cmap='YlGnBu',metric = 'correlation',z_score=0) 

    return g.fig

#Generating tkinter window
root = tkinter.Tk()
figure = create_plot()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

But be aware that seaborn creates a pyplot figure. Embedding a pyplot figure in a custom GUI may cause problems (note how none of the examples from the matplotlib page on embedding use pyplot!).